# Glassfish SQLite Datasource

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, glassfish

I am trying to add a JDBC Resource to my glassfish server, however I cannot ping it. I tried [this tutorial](http://sourceforge.net/p/sqlite-connpool/wiki/How%20To%20Setup%20a%20SQLite%20Connection%20Pool%20on%20Glassfish/)  but it seems like it cannot find the JDBC driver.

I get the following error:

> Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : org.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPoolDataSource

I read in another post on stackoverflow that I have to add the driver in "glassfish4/glassfish/domains/[domainname]/lib"

In glassfish 4 there are the subfolders:

- applibs
- classes
- databases
- ext

I tried to copy it in "ext", in "databases" and in the root folder "lib", but still I cannot ping it.

My glassfish server is: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 (build 89)

And the JDBC Driver I use is: sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar

Answer (score 1):

sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar doesn't contain such class. May be this helps http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-connpool/

Comment: Ah. Okay... Thanks for the tip! Does it matter where I copy it in the lib folder?

Comment: in lib folder is okay